# separate Primefaces css and other css styles

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

When I use primefaces components in my own templated(mostly bootstrap) website they override each other's css attributes.

- I can play with reordering resources *but this doesn't solve the problem totaly because eider way some css attributes between the primefaces css and template css will be overriden*.
- I can create my own primefaces css or change the current general
  template *but this will cost me months I think.*

So, How can I completely separate **primefaces css** from the **general template css** of the website so that primefaces css attributes cannot be overridden or they cannot override other css's attributes? Some system which will make them use only their own intended css attributes(or files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete idea of the CSS is the C = Cascading.

Your request is to delete the Cascading from the equation.

PrimeFaces CSS shouldn't have a conflict with any other CSS rules of PrimeFaces, the CSS is for the components.

It's more likely that you want bootstrap to take the "Master" CSS guider, in that case you should do the ordering using facets, PrimeFaces includes the resources in the `first` facet:

```
<f:facet name="middle">
    <!-- bootstrap goes here -->
</f:facet>
```

From my personal experience overriding PrimeFaces rules into bootstrap ones didn't toke months !

Or you should take the hard way which is having PrimeFaces without a theme

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
   <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This approach takes too much time to figure out the basic CSS needed for the component, I would rather have the default theme and override these rules.